# Minimu sum of difference of corresponding elements in 2 array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, optimization

This question had been asked in my coding round, But till today I am not able to come up with optimal algorithm.

I have given 2 arrays of size n.n can be varying from [1,16].and element of array can be varying from [0,10^9].

Like,

> array a1=[4,6,9]
> array a2=[5,10,1]

So I have to permute a1 in such a way that the corresponding index element difference is minimized.

So here,

> if a1 is permuted to [9,6,4] then answer will |9-5| + |6-10| + |4-1|
> =4+4+3 =11
>
> if a1 is permuted to [6,9,4] then answer will |6-5| + |9-10| + |4-1|
> =1+1+3 =5

So we have to give the minimum possible answer, among all the possible permutation of a1.

One simple approach is checking all the permutation of array. But it will be n!.

And another solution I come up is that, arrange a1's element according to arrangement of a2.means structure of a2 is like

> a2=[6,9,4]  ==> a2=[2nd min, 3rd min, 1st min]

So, I will try to fix 2nd element of a1 in staring index and so on till 1st min in ending index.
Then,

> a1 will look like a1=[2nd min, 3rd min, 1st min] ==> [6,9,4]

and this way found answer will be optimal, but I don't have any proof to show that, answer found using second method will give me correct answer.

Can you help me to prove that above algorithm is correct or not?
Also, is there any other optimal algorithm possible to solve this problem??

Comment: If you are only interested by the minimum sum, not by the corresponding permutation, then you can begin by sorting first the two arrays etc.

Comment: You mean I can go with the approach I describe ?? Sorry I am not getting, what you want to convey. Can you please explain more?

Comment: Both approaches are equivalent, simpler to simply sort both arrays. In the last case, you can demonstrate the optimality by *reductio ad absurdum*

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks for responding !

Comment: But I have one more question, Is this true that this approach will give correct answer or there are edge cases, where it fails??

Comment: I cannot see edge cases when it will fail. You may try to implement it and test it!